# How to run a Junit5 test with Android dependencies and robolectric

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, junit5, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run a unit test like that:

```
    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void junit5codeCoverage() {
        final int result = new Foo().junit5();

        Assert.assertEquals(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread(), Thread.currentThread());

        assertEquals(-1, result);
    }
```

That is a **Junit5** test with Android dependencies (i.e `Looper.getMainLooper()`) with Robolectric.

I am using the [junit5 android plugin from mannodermaus](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5) that allows running junit5 within Android setups. But this does not work out of the box because it would not load robolectric. So I tried [alixwar's branch](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5/pull/18#issuecomment-339903930) that would tackle robolectric and junit5 test coverage, but still, would not use Android classes.

I furthermore started to investigate how to run a robolectric test on junit5, which would require understanding how the `RobolectricTestRunner` works and how to port the code to the JUnit5 platform. I have little understanding of the new junit5 platform, but I figured out that I could build on top of the `org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform` runner, to follow the test runner concept, which is part of the `junit-platform-runner` package. But this is so far away from the original Junit4 `SandBoxTestRunner` that I couldn't manage to complete the port.

So what would be the most feasible path to implement robolectric junit5 support, or is there any (obvious) concept I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `junit-vintage-engine` to run test with runners from JUnit4.

Just add [`org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine) to your dependencies, thus you can `org.junit.runner.RunWith` annotation to your tests.

Comment: More details about the above answer: What this means is that you'll need to use JUnit4 @Test for tests that use @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class). And I suggest removing your JUnit 4 dependency from the gradle build: testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'  // should get rid of this old JUnit.

Comment: Big picture is: let's encourage Roboelectric to move to Jupiter so we can drop these special cases.

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to do this too, but it seems that at the time of this writing, Robolectric simply does not support junit5.

See the discussion here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2996

Some workarounds are described in that discussion, but for now I am just going to stick to junit4.

Comment: Is there any news on this after 1.5 years? Would be great to use JUnit5 with robolectric!

Comment: 2020 and that Issue is still open :o

Comment: Even now, 2022, the issue is still open!

Comment: 2023 .... *crickets*

Comment: 2024: still waiting...