# How to get Context in unit test to create Room database in memory database object

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, koin

I'm trying to test this one function in my application repository class which performs a database insertion. I'm using `Koin` as my dependency injection library. To do the testing I need to create a Database version that gets built in memory. To create that database I need the Android application context. So I created my test class like below.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import com.chathuranga.shan.mycontacts.di.applicationModule
import com.chathuranga.shan.mycontacts.di.repositoryModule
import com.chathuranga.shan.mycontacts.room.AppDatabase
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Test

import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.core.context.loadKoinModules
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.core.context.stopKoin
import org.koin.dsl.module
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.inject
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

class ContactRepositoryTest : KoinTest {

    private val contactRepository: ContactRepository by inject()
    private lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        startKoin {
            printLogger()
            modules(listOf(applicationModule,repositoryModule))
        }

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        //val instrumentationContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

        appDatabase = Room
            .inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()

        loadKoinModules(module { single(override = true) { appDatabase } })
    }

    @Test
    fun insertContact() {

        val firstName = "Chathuranga"
        val secondName = "Shan"
        val phone = "07711247890"

        contactRepository.insertContact(firstName,secondName,phone,null,null)

    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        stopKoin()
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this exception.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under registering instrumentation.**

As you can see I tried two ways to get `Context` (check the commented line in above class) and both failed the same way. And error pointed to the place where I create `Context` object. This test class in `test` folder not in `androidTest` folder. I want to separate this function and other functions that gonna come in the future and test in this class.

Here are my dependencies

```
//Testing
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0"
testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

My dependency injection class.

```
val applicationModule = module {
    single { AppDatabase.getDatabaseInstance(androidContext().applicationContext) }
}

val activityModule = module {

    scope(named<MainActivity>()) {
        scoped { (activity: MainActivity) ->
            Navigation
                .findNavController(activity, R.id.hostFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to testing. If the way I have grasped the concept of unit testing please point it out. Otherwise 
Point out the problem with this code. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Koin then u should not have any problem?where is DAO file ? u have to Mock it in @Before , share your repository and DAO file

Comment: I know, before even implement that this problem occurred. What is wrong with the way I try to create this Room database instance?

Answer (score 7):

## Create Context with Robolectric in a local unit test

For local unit tests run on the JVM, Robolectric works. If this is in an instrumented test, then Robolectric is not needed. `InstrumentationRegistry` can be used as in [Joe Birch's sample](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-architecture-components-testing-your-room-dao-classes-e06e1c9a1535).

### 1. Add libraries

#### JUnit 5

*build.gradle*

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:X.X.X"
testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:X.X.X"
```

- [Getting Started](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) - Robolectric
- [AndroidX Gradle dependenceies](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#gradle-dependencies) - Android documentation

#### Junit 4

Built-in use with JUnit 4 and AndroidX library.

- [`testImplementation "androidx.test:core:X.X.X"`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests)

### 2. Create app Context with `ApplicationProvider`

#### Junit 5

*See: Build local unit tests > [Include framework dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#include-framework-dependencies) - Android documentation*

*SomeTest.kt*

```
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SomeTest {

    @Test
    fun someTest() {
        val appContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        ...
    }

}
```

#### JUnit 4

*See: Robolectric's [documentation](http://robolectric.org/androidx_test/)*

### 3. Handle SDK 29/Java 9 error with class annotation `@Config`

*See: [How to add Java 9 to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467224/2253682) - StackOverflow*

Comment: I'm really thankful for this detailed answer. I'll try this out

Comment: Why not use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context`?

Comment: That seems promising as well per Joe Birch's sample linked above.

Comment: Is the reference to **JUnit5** erroneous or did you really get to use Robolectric+JUnit5? I wasted a lot of time trying to use Robolectric + JUnit5 but without success, and according to other answers this is not possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51566798/13303234 and the issue linked there. All the links in your paragraphs titled "JUnit5" actually refer to documentation on JUnit4, and nothing in the code points to JUnit5.